# How to handle File::Find on Windows with long paths

Tags: perl

I've been trying to use Perl's File:Find to recursively find all files on my Windows system drive.  Unfortunately it errors out during execution to a very long file path.  I would like to know how to handle this in a way such that my script can continue running and let me know which paths it had to skip.  Currently I can only count files until it encounters a path it doesn't like, at which point it stops.

What I was basing this off: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=217166
I found the following article, which is a similar problem, but am unable to apply it:  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=933849

```
#/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use File::Find;    
my $superFileCount = 0;
# first try find(\&print_name_if_dir, no_chdir=>1, ".");

# second try
eval {
find(\&print_name, no_chdir=>1, ".")
}; warn $@ if $@;
# end of second try

sub print_name
{
        $superFileCount++;
}
print "all files found: $superFileCount \n";
```

First run:

```
Can't cd to ../../../../../../../../../.. from ./Users/username/AppData/Roaming/
Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/8Z5RPFSR/foxnewsplayer-a.akamaihd.net/[[I
MPORT]]/players.edgesuite.net/flash/plugins/osmf/advanced-streaming-plugin/v3.6/
osmf2.0/AkamaiAdvancedStreamingPlugin.swf: No such file or directory at C:/Straw
berryPerl/perl/lib/File/Find.pm line 812.
```

If I wrap it in eval, I get a partial filecount but it is much lower than what is actually on the drive:

```
Can't cd to ../../../../../../../../../.. from ./Users/username/AppData/Roaming/
Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/8Z5RPFSR/foxnewsplayer-a.akamaihd.net/[[I
MPORT]]/players.edgesuite.net/flash/plugins/osmf/advanced-streaming-plugin/v3.6/
osmf2.0/AkamaiAdvancedStreamingPlugin.swf: No such file or directory at C:/Straw
berryPerl/perl/lib/File/Find.pm line 812.
all files found: 84730
```

Comment: Your script works just fine for me.  I am, however, running Cygwin.

Comment: That may make a difference, I'm using Strawberry Perl.  Perhaps Cygwin handles the path differently.  I'm hoping there is a way to manage the error more effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `no_chdir` parameter (or any parameter for that matter), you need to enclose all your params in a hash reference. You're not, which is why `no_chdir` isn't taking effect. Try this:

```
find({ wanted => \&print_name, no_chdir => 1 }, '.');
```

I don't know however if this will actually fix your problem, as it could simply be the actual path isn't being processed properly, and may not have anything to do with doing a `cd`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction regarding the hash reference.  That was the problem-- once it was receiving the no_chdir parameter it avoided/handled the problematic path.